# How to subtract datetime based on conditon

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
  empid empname          logtime                    Type
  -----------------------------------------------------
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 09:26:00.000   IN
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 09:26:00.000   OUT
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 09:51:00.000   IN
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 10:08:00.000   OUT
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 11:48:00.000   IN
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 11:58:00.000   OUT
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 12:15:00.000   IN
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 12:48:00.000   OUT
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 13:06:00.000   IN
   8    Mohan Varma   2013-10-30 13:19:00.000   OUT
```

My table structure is like that . I  have to calculate the no. of `hours`based on `IN/OUT`.
can any one suggest me how to do?.I didnt worked on this requirement till date.

Comment: Where is the problem? what you have tried?

Comment: @Bhagavan i tried to calculate the time(hours) between IN/Out of employee.but i am not able to solve it..

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `empids` are different i.e. each empid has IN and OUT. If this is true then, you can do by this way

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, t1.logtime , t2.logtime)
FROM empTable t1, empTable t2
WHERE t1.empid = t2.empid AND t1.Type = 'IN' AND t2.Type = 'OUT'
```